# How to Automate Cropping Images?

Tags: mac, automator, graphics, image-editing

Is there any way to automate cropping images on Mac? (Not the whole file, but part of the file.)

I've tried this with Automator but the cropping function just makes the *whole* image smaller instead of chopping the part that I don't want off of the image.

Answer (score 15):

You may use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) in order to crop from command line. That way you may include the command inside an Applescript, or call the command directly from terminal.

You can install it following [these instructions](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) and then you crop all images inside a folder, given:

> convert '*.jpg' -crop 120x120+10+5 thumbnail%03d.png

where 120x120 is the resulting size and 10+5 is the offset (10 pixels width and 5 pixels height).

Comment: Alternate installation method: install from the command-line with `brew install imagemagick` ftw!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Xcode installed, you could download and compile and install (via Automator's import menu) [Convert Images to Letterbox Format (completed)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AutomatorHandsOn/Listings/Convert_Images_to_Letterbox_Format__completed__main_applescript.html) from Apple's developer library. That action crops without resizing. Look for the "Download Sample Code" at the top-left of the linked page