# Is it possible to control dimensions of cropping an image?

Tags: macos, image-editing

I'm looking for a tool that can help reshape images to specific dimensions, but I'm not sure if there's a term easy to search for tools that support that.

Preview can resize images to specific dimensions, but at the cost of losing dimension ratio. However you can create a square here in preview to specify how to crop, then to zoom in our out of image to get the crop you want, however you cannot specify that crop dimensions, only the image dimensions.

Is there a software or a key term for feature that can help you specify crop dimension? (not image dimension)

Example: Here I have to carefully drag the border to make it a square, but is there a way to create a crop area with predefined dimensions?]

[image]

Comment: Also - dozens of related questions with answers on the side bar here to the right: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/how-to-automate-cropping-images

Comment: @bmike I'm not asking about automation. I'm asking about the ability to specify crop dimension

Comment: Yes, you program the dimensions into the tool so you don’t need to use a mouse or do you not know how to crop in photos app or acorn or Pixelmator and just need an app suggestion?

Comment: I was wondering about existing application, if I resort to programming scripts for automation, I can just resort to openCV

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs you might resize all images first, then specify the crop and potentially resize again after if needed. It's really up to your workflow which operation needs to happen in which order.

[image]

Photos manually (which also has a very nice square crop tool and can export and re-sample the image if needed). The next step would be to have  automator or AppleScript control Photos (or your editor of choice) to make entering specific dimensions easier. If you don't mind shell scripting, the tool I've used to script this for many images is https://www.imagemagick.org/

You can get it with https://brew.sh and install quite easily. You should spend 10 minutes installing brew and the command line tools (free) from Apple and skip installing Xcode unless you feel you want the whole developer toolset. That might take 30 minutes or more to install.

There are dozens of tutorials on how to do this - here are three:

- https://www.macworld.com/article/1153762/resize_images_automator.html
- https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how_to_batch_convert_and_resize_images_with_automator
- https://9to5mac.com/2016/04/27/how-to-quickly-resize-images-mac-using-automator-service/

Comment: Does it let you choose what part you want to keep in the cropped area?

Comment: @Iancovici -  Like Blade Runner where you speak and ask to enhance on the fly, no. Like if you know the coordinates or can do math to specify what you want to keep, yes.